# ¿Como acceder a mas de una clase en una funcion keyup Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, funciones

Ejemplo de codigo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="uno" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" id="dos" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" id="tre" class="prueba">
    <input type="text" id="cua" class="prueba">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- ATENCION AQUI -->
    <script>
        $(document).on('keyup', '.demostracion', function() {
            console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    </script>
    <!-- ------------- -->

</body>

</html>
```

Ok, llevo investigando pero no doy con la respuesta. El `console.log` va a imprimirme los `id` de los `input` con la clase `demostracion` sobre los cuales se interactúen gracias al `$(this).attr('id')`, pero ¿Cómo haría para ahí también imprimir el `id` de los `input` que tienen la clase `prueba`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si mal no entiendo, quieres incluir diferentes clases en el evento `keyup`. De ser así sólo es necesario separar con coma las clases que quieras incluir. Algo así...

```
...$(document).on('keyup', '.demostracion, .prueba', function() {...
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="uno" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" id="dos" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" id="tre" class="prueba">
    <input type="text" id="cua" class="prueba">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- ATENCION AQUI -->
    <script>
        $(document).on('keyup', '.demostracion, .prueba', function() {
            console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    </script>
    <!-- ------------- -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola pruebe lo soguiente

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="uno" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" id="dos" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" id="tre" class="prueba">
    <input type="text" id="cua" class="prueba">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- ATENCION AQUI -->
    <script>
        $(document).on('keyup', '.demostracion, .prueba', function() {
            console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    </script>
    <!-- ------------- -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no soluciona mi problema al 100... De igual manera gracias

Comment: Que falta para solucionar el 100%, de esa forma obtienes los id de los elementos con la clase `prueba` que falta por resolver

Comment: Bueno... No necesito que traiga un array con los ids de la clase cada que se ejecuta la función, me es preciso que traiga el id solo del input sobre el cual se esta interactuando... Como los que tienen el id `uno` y `dos`

Comment: ah ya entendía la pregunta, edito mi respuesta, es que entendí que necesitaba los `id` de la clase prueba, fue un mal entendido

Comment: de todos modos ya @DjCrazy había dado la respuesta correcta

Answer (score 1):

No lo sé, siento que te complicas de más. El evento de keyup es o debería de ser utilizado por elementos interactivos, en este caso son inputs, por lo que deberíamos enfocarnos en los inputs, no en las clases

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
   const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[class]");

   inputs.forEach(e=> inputs[e]. addeventlistener ("keyup", evt=> {
      ....
   })
});
```

Comment: Es cierto, puede parecer complicado, pero el hecho es, que el código de arriba es solo un ejemplo sencillo que di para ver si alguien podía darme una respuesta para dar con la solución a mi problema original. Lo que planteas esta muy bien, pero no puedo hacerlo así ya que tengo muchísimos formularios e inputs y solo necesito que funcione con una pequeña cantidad de ellos, por eso los separe por clases... Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!